# Installation error in hue , permission denied error

Tags: bigdata, hue

When i try to install from "Install individual application examples" tab in hue

"hive editor" and "spark"

It shows error of type

"Permission denied. Please check with your system administrator."

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by create superuser with the same name as created in hadoop